# Using plywood for vertical shelving?

Tags: plywood, strength

I want to build some shelving (actually, on wheels, for use as a rolling cart) and I'd like to use 3/4" hardwood plywood for the whole thing, because it's cheaper than wood boards and I'm going to paint it, so things like grain and appearance are not so critical. This will be for kitchen stuff, not books, so there will be some weight, but lighter duty than bookshelves. The horizontal span will be 3', the height 6', and the shelf depth 6".

My question is: can I use plywood for the vertical sides of the shelving as well as the shelves? Is 3/4" plywood strong enough for load perpendicular to the plies for this kind of use?

Comment: I think if you do a search for plywood shelving or plywood storage you'll find out what you need to know here (spoiler alert: yes 3/4" hardwood ply is more than good enough for the casework on something like this). You can even look up shop storage and rolling carts and you'll find multiple projects.

Comment: For the shelving, you might want to put in hardwood edging just to add a little or a lot to the stiffness there, might not be necessary but can't hurt.

Comment: 3/4" plywood is more than strong enough for this if used correctly.  Make sure you do something (like a solid back or corner braces) to prevent racking, and that the joinery you use for your shelves is strong enough.  Over a 6' vertical span you'll also want to include at least one fixed shelf to prevent the sides from bowing outwards.

Comment: I'd also be very worried about putting something 6' tall and 6" deep on wheels.  That's going to be very easy to tip if it hits a bump.  Is this supposed to be something like a pull-out pantry?  Those are more typically done with slides, not wheels.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232: Thanks for the tip about the corner bracing. And yes, this is tall and narrow because it's going to be sliding between the wall and the fridge, so it can't topple. I should probably put in a stopper of some kind so you cannot pull it out past the fridge, so it can't fall. I could mount it to the wall and have it slide, but I think that would require some serious sliding hardware. Do you have any suggestions on that?

Comment: How are you planning on attaching the shelves? If you're using ply for the shelves, screws into the end "grain" of plywood doesn't work very well.

Comment: There are slides specifically designed for pull-out pantries: https://www.cabinetparts.com/p/fulterer-drawer-slides-bottom-mount-pantry-slides-FULFR77530-p23105?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIp4uEnpCC7AIVOx-tBh26OAOZEAQYAiABEgIPEPD_BwE  If that is price-prohibitive I bet that two sets of side-mount slides, one at the top and one at the bottom, would work just fine.

Comment: @FreeMan: I've been thinking about that. I was thinking of cutting a 1/4" groove/mortise into the vertical board and a corresponding tenon into the shelves. But that might be tricky to get right, and maybe not work well on plywood. Or maybe pocket screws, for which I have the jig. What would you recommend?

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232: Indeed, that hardware is too expensive for this little project. The side mounts probably wouldn't work, because one side is a metal refrigerator and I can't mount anything to it. But as long as the cart can't slide past where it's supported by wall and fridge to the sides, I don't think I need to worry about tipping.

Comment: I believe that there are quite a few cabinet building questions 'round here. You may want to do some searching. There are tons of web sites and books on cabinetry that you can look at, as well.

Comment: "one side is a metal refrigerator and I can't mount anything to it."  Build a cabinet around your shelves and mount the slides to that.  You're kind of re-inventing the wheel here.  There's nothing wrong with the way you're thinking about doing this, it just isn't the normal solution.  The only thing that I'd recommend is that if you're going to use casters use all fixed casters so that the casters don't flip around and wobble the shelves every time you start moving it.

Comment: Good advice above (especially the part about putting something like a back on it to prevent racking... it doesn't even have to be a full back: 3 stretchers would probably be fine). What I really wanted to note is that you could make the unit sturdier by going to a baltic birch type of plywood (more plies, no voids), compared to the typical crap that the big box home centers sell. Side benefit of baltic birch: the edges might be attractive enough that you don't feel a need to edge them.